# Subscribe to edge.create in Page Tab

Tags: javascript, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-page

My Page Tab tells people to Like the page using the Like Button next to the title of the Page (directly above the iframe).

How do I subscribe to that event being clicked?

Javascript within the Page Tab **does not** work:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {            
        alert('clicked like button');
    }
);
```

Thanks!

**EDIT: For now, I'm going with "you can't do it" as the answer...**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`edge.create` is to be used with the [Facebook Like *Plugin*](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/). It **won't** fire when the like button next to the page name is clicked.

The page will get reloaded once the button is clicked.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. I want to track the latter with google analytics. Any ideas?

Comment: No idea, but I don't think this is possible. Since that button is out-side your iframe.